# In Meteor can I capture or pass the link/anchor text in the event when user clicks a link?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to set a Session variable to the text that a user clicks on when they click a link. For example if the link is `<a href="/link">The Link</a>`.

I would like to `Session.set('clickedLink', <<The Link>>);` but with "The Link" obviously replaced with the text string that the user has clicked on.

Is this possible? Am I going about this all wrong?

I figured I might be able to use something like:

```
Template.SingleQuote.events({
  "click .link": function (event) {
    Session.set("currentPageName", event.a.text);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.target.text`.

```js
Template.SingleQuote.events({
    'click .link'(event) {
        Session.set('currentPageName', event.target.text);
    }
});
```

---

**Edit:**

Instead of what has been posted, it has been suggested by reviewers that I update this answer to make use of the following syntax:

```js
'click .link': function(event) { /* ... */ }
```

Both of these are perfectly valid syntax for a Meteor Template Event, use whichever you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks, yes this worked. Note: one of my links contained an <em> and so event.target.text returned "" so either using innerText or just moving the <em> out of the a tag fixed this.